# Does sub folders in s3 bucket will be affected when we use life cycle policy with prefix?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my project, I have to setup lifecycle policies to control S3 usage and capacity. We have multiple folder inside a bucket. I have created policy with prefix based on our requirement. But I can see the changes only inside the prefix folder not inside its subfolders.

For Example:

I have a bucket -> Project_Docs
Below that i got a folders Excel, Word, Powerpoint
Under Excel, i have subfolders as 2020, 2021 etc.

If i create the policy with Excel, it impacts only the files under Excel folder and not attentive for its subfolder 2020 and 2021.

Please help me to overcome this.

Comment: Please show the current lifecycle configuration. You can run this command to get it: aws s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket <YOUR_BUCKET_NAME>

Comment: {
            "ID": "Bw_6MonthsRetention_20211207",
            "Filter": {
                "Prefix": "Excel/"
            },
            "Status": "Enabled",
            "Transitions": [
                {
                    "Days": 180,
                    "StorageClass": "STANDARD_IA"
                }
            ]
        }

Comment: It seems to be ok. For new rules it can take up to 48 hours to complete the first run. When the rule was created?

Comment: The rule created on 12/07/2021. 
When you say ok, does it mean the rule is applicable for its subfolders too? Please clear me on this.

Comment: Any update on this??

Comment: @SarathkumarUdayakumar I am also facing same issue. In your case  was "Excel/" working fine for sub-folders after 48 hours or something else is solution? please help on this